# How can i access a database from docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, go, go-gorm

I need to access MySQL database that I created outside docker but I am getting an error how can I access my database?

```
panic: failed to connect database
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.init.0()
    /go/src/app/src/main.go:33 +0x12c
```

Comment: I don't have a container for the database

Comment: the database connection is configured *somewhere* - you need to make sure you pass that information into your docker container - and that the network the DB is on is visible from inside your docker environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the current recommended way to do it, but here is what has worked for me in the past on different OS's:

OSX: set the mysql host to `docker.for.mac.localhost`

Windows: set the mysql host to `host.docker.internal` (this should work on OSX also)

Linux: set the mysql host to  `172.17.0.1`.

Depending on how you installed mysql, you may need to find its `my.cnf` configuration and change the `bind_address` value to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is, by taking a mysql dump of the database and copying that file inside a directory with path `$HOME/docker/volumes/mysql` of host machine and mapping it to the docker container using `--volume` flag.

1. Take the dump of the databse by executing this command : `mysqldump -u root -proot dnName > dbName.dat.sql` (replace dbName with your database name).
2. Create a Mysql docker container and use the volume flag to map the files from host to contanier while executing the docker tun command: `-v $HOME/docker/volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`.
3. Import that dumo into container's mysql . `mysql -u root -proot dbName < dbName.dat.sql`.